# Transferring touch event back to parent

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. I know I can intercept the touch events using the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method in the `ScrollView`. But once the child, i.e. ListView, starts consuming the touch event, onInterceptTouchEvent is not call. My problem is how can I transfer the touch event back to parent(i.e. `ScrollView`) once the `ListView` scroll has reached top. I want the scroll to be in continuation.

Suppose I'm scrolling the `ListView` and have reached the top of the `ListView` I want the scroll to continue so that I can scroll the parent, i.e. ScrollView. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you are at the top of the listview, then return false from the touch event.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. The event is still consumed by the listview.

Comment: Post your code? Off the top of my head it may depend on returning for which motion event action.